# Implied expressions with same probability

Tags: probability, random-variable, notation

Given two variables $a$ and $b$ and two intervals $I$ and $J$, is the following affirmation true? $$
\Pr[a\in I]\geq p\ \land\ (a\in I\implies b\in J) \implies \Pr[b\in J]\geq p
$$

Of course, $a\in I$ and $b\in J$ both depend on one or more random variables; otherwise, it wouldn't make sense to speak about probabilities.

In case it's not true, I would like to see the proof. I have no idea where to start, and I would like to know also if there's some minimum set of requirements that would make that affirmation true.

Comment: It depends on what kind of proof you want but essentially $a\in I\implies b\in J$ will give you $\Pr[a \in I] \le \Pr[b \in J]$

Comment: @Henry has your affirmation any name or something I can search for? I would like to see the proof.

Comment: This is often taken as an axiom of probability: namely, that when $\mathcal{E}\subset\mathcal{F}$ are events, $\Pr(\mathcal E)\le \Pr(\mathcal F).$ From such a perspective there is nothing left to show.  Even when it's not taken as axiomatic, it is readily derivable from some related axiom: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms#Monotonicity for instance.

Comment: @whuber Ok. Enough for me. Promote it as an answer and I will flag it as the right one.

Comment: Wouldn't [one of a set of closely related threads](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=probability+axiom+monoton*) serve even better?

Comment: @whuber Thinking further about this, how do you go from $a\in I\implies b\in J$ to a $S_a\subseteq S_b$ relation? You would need to be able to construct a set $S_a$ from $a\in I$ and $S_b$ from $b\in I$ so that $a\in I\implies b\in J \equiv S_a\subseteq S_b$ and then apply the probability axiom. But how do you guarantee that $S_a$ and $S_b$ even exists? I don't think my question should be closed because that equivalence is kinda intuitive but not so obvious to prove for me.

Comment: It is a matter of set theory and the definition of random variable.  Now that you have identified the nature of the problem, I think you have adequately distinguished your question from those others (+1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really a question about sets and mathematical notation, so let's unravel the notation.

Random variables are, first of all, *functions.*  Abstractly their domains are a sample space $\Omega$ and we don't need to be concerned with their codomains (usually, but not always, the set of real numbers).  Thus we may more formally and explicitly write

$$(a,b):\Omega \to \mathcal{X}_a \times \mathcal{X}_b$$

where the codomain of the *bivariate* random variable $(a,b)$ is the Cartesian product of their individual codomains.

In this context, $I \subseteq \mathcal{X}_a$ and $J\subseteq\mathcal{X}_b$ are certain subsets of these codomains.  The conditions potentially constrain the possible values of $a$ and $b:$

- $a\in I$ refers to that set of observations $\omega\in\Omega$ for which $a(\omega)\in I,$ written $a^{-1}(I).$
- $b\in J$ refers to that set of observations $\omega\in\Omega$ for which $b(\omega)\in J,$ written $b^{-1}(J).$

Therefore, "$a\in I\implies b\in J$" means that if $a(\omega)\in I$ then $b(\omega)\in J.$  See the figure.

[image: Figure]

Equivalently, this can be expressed as

$$\text{For all }\omega\in\Omega,\ \omega \in a^{-1}(I)\implies \omega \in b^{-1}(J).$$  But this is the very *definition* of set inclusion, whence

$$a^{-1}(I) \subseteq b^{-1}(J).$$

The *monotone axiom* of probability says the probability of a subset is no greater than the probability of any set in which it is contained.  In particular, combining this with the assumptions in the question, we see

$$p \le \Pr(a \in I) = \Pr(a^{-1}(I)) \le \Pr(b^{-1}(J)) = \Pr(b\in J).$$

The first "$\le$" is an assumption in the question; the "$=$" are the notation explained above; and the middle "$\le$" arises from applying the monotone axiom.

Comment: I don't know if this little fact changes everything but, I said that "both $a\in I$ and $b\in J$ depends on a random variable"; that doesn't mean that $a$ and $b$ are both random variables. It might happen that $a$ is a random variable but $b$ is not, while $J$ is defined as $J=[f_1(a), f_2(a)]$ and thus $J$ depends on the random variable $a$, which is a totally valid way to speak about probabilities, like $\Pr[b\in [\min(a, \sin(a)), \max(a, \sin(a))]]$.

Comment: It is difficult to make sense of an expression like "$\Pr(a\in I)$" unless either $a$ is a random variable or $I$ is a random interval.  The latter is such an unlikely interpretation that I think readers are compelled to understand that both $a$ and $b$ are random variables.

Comment: If $X$ is a random variable, isn't $[\min(X, \sin(X)), \max(X, \sin(X))]$ a random interval because it depends on a random variable?