# Probability, set theory and predicates

Tags: probability, set-theory

If $P(t_1,\ldots,t_{n+m})$ is some predicate depending on $n+m$ terms (for example $x\leq c$ depends on two terms), and each $X_i$ is a discrete random variable with support $\Omega_i$, and each $c_i$ is some constant, is this definition correct?
$$
\Pr\left[P(X_1,\ldots, X_n, c_1\ldots,c_m)\right]=\sum_{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in W}\Pr\left[(X_1,\ldots,X_n)=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\right]
$$
where $W=\{(w_1,\ldots,w_n)\in\Omega_1\times\cdots\times\Omega_n\mid P(w_1,\ldots,w_n,c_1,\ldots,c_m)\}$.

For example, if I have a discrete random variable $X$ and two constants $c_1$ and $c_2$, is this correct (intentionally uncommon example)? $$
\Pr\left[c_1X\geq \sqrt{X+c_1}\log(c_2)\right]=\sum_{x\in \{w\in\Omega\mid c_1w\geq \sqrt{w+c_1}\log(c_2)\}}\Pr[X=x]
$$

Comment: This is usually not correct unless the probability distribution is discrete.  Consider the case $n=1,$ $m=0,$ and $X_1$ is a uniform random variable on $[0,1].$

Comment: Can't the symbol $\sum$ be used for continuous sets as a generalized way to express addition? Because an integral is the sum of a continuous set of summands. I need a symbol to express that generalization, and I thought $\sum$ was it.

Comment: No: that's what you need integration for.

Comment: @whuber I have updated the question because restricting the support to discrete variables is OK for me. Is it correct now?

Comment: Since the $c_i$ are fixed throughout, they play no role; and you can take $(X_1,\ldots, X_n)$ to be a *single* vector-valued random variable.  Recognizing these facts will hugely simplify your question and, I hope, make the result obvious: it is a way of stating an axiom of probability; namely, that the probability of a countable union of disjoint events is the sum of their probabilities.

Comment: @whuber My doubt was more focus on the construction of the set $W$, I wasn't sure whether the "set to sum" can be constructed the same way for any arbitrary predicate you can think of, and without changing the probability distribution of $X$ either (which is good news because of its simplicity and uniformity). Also, I'm curious to know if the property I presented in the question is derived from probability axioms or it's a definition by itself.

Comment: @whuber Extra note: as you have probably noticed already, that question is a generalization of your answer to my other question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/567833/implied-expressions-with-same-probability/568279?noredirect=1#comment1048221_568279